Is there a way to customize target folder for Tauri build
By default, cargo tauri build build the target bundle at the root_project_direct/target folder. But is there a way to customize the path ?Since the project folder is in a temp folder on CI and being cleanup after each build, we would like to save the build target files to a separate folder. But I can't find such an option in tauri.conf.json

Consider adding a CI step to move the files to the desired location after compilation.

What CI system are you using? GitLab for example allows you define artifacts that are the output (and are kept) of a build job. There is also caching if you need the output in subsequent jobs. I'm sure GitHub and many other CI platforms have a similar concept.

@FinnBear, moving after unfortunately is missing the point because the purpose is to cache the target folder. It is on Jenkins as we have a cleanup policy after each build.
I found the solution is to use CARGO_TARGET_DIR

@MindSwipe, I am using Jenkins, and found the solution by setting CARGO_TARGET_DIR env var.
